# In a major tennis tournament match, what was the largest difference in points won and lost where the winner lost more points?

Tags: tennis, records

In a Major (a.k.a. "Grand Slam") tennis tournament, what is the largest difference in total points won versus total points lost in a match where the winner of the match won fewer total points than the player that lost the match. Which tournament and players were involved and which round of the tournament did it occur in?

Also, what if this question was limited to only the Quarterfinal, Semifinal or Final rounds?

Comment: Welcome to SE.Sport. Could you please re-write the question is a better way? It is not clear to me what you asking

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you are asking about matches such as [2009 Australian Open final](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_Australian_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles_final#Statistics), where Feder lost the match, but he won one more point than Nadal.

Comment: 24 points difference (478 to 502) in the famous [Isner-Mahut match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isner%E2%80%93Mahut_match_at_the_2010_Wimbledon_Championships#Match_statistics) seems like a good candidate. According to a study made on sample of 61000 ATP and GS matches, in about 4.5% of matches the winner of the match has less total points, see [here](http://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2014/01/what-every-pro-tennis-player-does-better-than-roger-federer/283007/).

Comment: You can find some matches of this kind here: [Winner has less points than loser](http://www.menstennisforums.com/2-general-messages/82854-winner-has-less-points-than-loser.html).
From the opposite end of spectrum: [Tennis match with the less percentage of points won by a player](http://www.menstennisforums.com/2-general-messages/394361-tennis-match-less-percentage-points-won-player.html). (Both links from menstennisforums.)

Comment: Thank you @Martin. I need exactly matches like 2009 AO final, where federer lost the match, but he won one more point than Nadal, in the last decade. Isner Mahut Match is I guess in 1st round Wimbledon which is of not much importance. I need crucial matches(such as Qf,Sf, Finals) where  loser won more points than winner. Thanks for the links

Comment: @Bert Since there were some votes to close the question as "unclear what you are asking", perhaps making the clarification in the post would be better than just in comments. (I guess that adding an example with an explanation how this example fulfills your criteria would make the post clear enough. Although I think that jamauss' edit helped making the wording clearer.)

Comment: 2013 kitzbuhel final granollers/monaco - 0-6 7-6(3) 6-4 => 11 points difference. 2013 marseille final tsonga/berdych 3-6 7-6(6) 6-4 => 11 points diff.  2014 santiago semifinal fognini/almagro 6-4 1-6 7-6(5) => 13 points diff. i can come up with more instances tomorrow :)